# Что задать двум блокам, чтобы они были равны 50% высоты

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Я задал двум правым элементам `flex: 1`, что нужно указать, чтобы высота этих двух блоков всегда была равна 50%? Т.е., чтобы высота каждого блока была 50% от высоты родительского контейнера, а другой блок не будет заполнять оставшуюся часть, а будет тоже равен половине высоты соседа.
Пример, как я хочу, чтобы работало: 
**Первый(1)** блок переполнился контентом, его высота равна 700px, **второму(2)** блоку хватает 400px для контента, но он растягивается до 700px.
Прикладываю также схематичную картинку примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ только на CSS, JavaScript нельзя использовать

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 max-width: 900px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 26px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.one, .two > div, .three > div {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
}

.two__One {
 flex: 1;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.two, .three {
 flex: 1;
}

.one {
 flex: 2;
 background-color: red;
        padding: 15px;
        height: auto;
}

.two {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.two > div {
 background-color: gold;
}

.three > div {
 background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 

  <div class="one">
      Super TSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Textext
  </div>
 <div class="two__One">
  <div class="two">
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
   <div>SuperSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text Text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что надо. Высота ж еще и от контента зависит.

Comment: @AlexDevTime ну да, когда один блок стал большим из-за переполнения контентом, к примеру 700px, то второй блок также должен быть 700px. Вот это я не понимаю как сделать

Comment: раз 20 перечитал вопрос, но всё равно ничего не понял )

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex я вроде даже пример написал, что я хочу, сейчас нарисую

Comment: Так блок `two__One` и так "растягивается" в зависимости от контента блока `one`

Comment: @E_K мне нужно, чтобы растягивались два блока справа `.two`, `.three`

Comment: Вы хотите, что бы если у блока `.two` высота `300px`, то и блок `.three` должен получить высоту `300px`?

Comment: @E_K да, я хочу это, я сейчас нарисую ещё пример

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего без гридов этого не сделать.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 max-width: 900px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 26px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.one, .two > div, .three > div {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
}

.two__One {
 flex: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
 display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.one {
 flex: 2;
 background-color: red;
        padding: 15px;
        height: auto;
}

.two > div {
 background-color: gold;
}

.three > div {
 background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 

  <div class="one">
      Super TSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Textext
  </div>
 <div class="two__One">
  <div class="two">
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
      <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
      <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
   <div>SuperSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text Text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Думаю, что можно, надо просто найти мастера по флексу

Comment: Сомневаюсь, вы хотите задавать высоту блоку в зависимости от его соседа. `Flexbox` хороший инструмент, но не всемогущ.

Comment: ваш ответ отвечает на мой вопрос, но хотелось бы увидеть без гридов, так как у них слабая поддержка. Я помечу ваш ответ правильным, если не появится ответа без гридов.

Comment: У гридов поддержка 92%, все современные браузеры.

Comment: @МихаилКамахин , в каком месте слабая поддержка? https://caniuse.com/#search=grid говорит об обратном..

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут либо `Grid`, либо `overflow: hidden || auto;`
Я бы выбрал Гриды, они будут меньше по коду, да и в общем они лучше выглядят.

Можно выбрать Флекс, но тут нужно будет фиксить `overflow` либо скрывая (`hidden`), либо задавать `overflow-y: auto;`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2surb0qh/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 700px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.wrapper.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper.flex .block {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.wrapper.flex .group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.wrapper.flex .group .block {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.wrapper.flex .group .block:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.wrapper.flex .group .block:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "block top-block" "block bottom-block";
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.wrapper.grid .block.br-red {
  grid-area: block;
}
.wrapper.grid .block.br-yellow {
  grid-area: top-block;
}
.wrapper.grid .block.br-pink {
  grid-area: bottom-block;
}

.block {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.block.br-red {
  border-color: red;
}
.block.br-yellow {
  border-color: yellow;
}
.block.br-pink {
  border-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<h1>С использованием Flex:</h1>
<div class="wrapper flex">
 <div class="block br-red">
   Super TSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Textext
 </div>
 <div class="group">
  <div class="block br-yellow">
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
   <div>SuperSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block br-pink">
   <div>SuperSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text Text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="group">
  <div class="block br-yellow">
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
   <div>SuperSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block br-pink">
   <div>SuperSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text Text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<hr>
<h1>С использованием Flex:</h1>
<div class="wrapper flex">
 <div class="block br-red">
   Super TSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Textext
 </div>
 <div class="group">
  <div class="block br-yellow">
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
   <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block br-pink">
   <div>SuperSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text Text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<hr>
<h1>С использованием Grid:</h1>
<div class="wrapper grid">
 <div class="block br-red">
   Super TSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Textext
 </div>
 <div class="block br-yellow">
  <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
  <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
  <div>Super TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="block br-pink">
  <div>SuperSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper TextSuper Text Text</div>
 </div>
</div>
```